# Office 2003 moving to 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2003

I am in the process of creating the custom install of Office 2010 for my company's enterprise.  Since the "Save My Settings" wizard is no longer available with the advent of Office 2010, is there any way to import an OPS file (Save My Settings Wizard) into an MSP (Office 2010 custom install file)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can customize your installation packages. Microsoft offers the *Office Customization Tool (OCT)*. Please read the [official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179132.aspx) for further information. With this tool you can create custom settings and also include updates to deploy a full patched office package.